# Redirect Write-Host statements to a file

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that I am debugging and would like to redirect all [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) statements to a file. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I just found Start-Transcript which outputs everything from your window to a file but does not seem to work yet when I add it to ps1 file.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Until PowerShell 4.0, `Write-Host` sends the objects to the host. It does not return any objects.
>
> Beginning with PowerShell 5.0 and newer, `Write-Host` is a wrapper for `Write-Information`, which allows to output to the information stream and redirect it with `6>> file_name`.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849877.aspx

However, if you have a lot of `Write-Host` statements, replace them all with `Write-Log`, which lets you decide whether output to console, file or event log, or all three.

Check also:

- [`Add-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156791.aspx)
- [redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347588.aspx) like `>, >>, 2>, 2>, 2>&1`
- [`Write-Log`](http://poshcode.org/2575)
- [Tee-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347705.aspx)
- [`Start-Transcript`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347721.aspx).

Comment: I don't think this is an answer.  In Powershell 3.0, if I try `write-host "test" > c:\temp\out.txt` I don't get anything in the file. the output is written to the console

Comment: @ekkis redirection operator is unuseful when applied to cmdlets without output, obviously

Comment: yes but the answer states that if I don't want to replace the write-host statements that I should "try to append redirection" - which is what I tried in my answer, which fails

Comment: I see, I wrote "try" actually. Thank you for your feedback, I corrected the answer with better indications hopefully.

Comment: [Write-Log in Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170123204619/https://poshcode.org/2575)

Answer (score 17):

You can create a proxy function for [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) which sends objects to the standard output stream instead of merely printing them. I wrote the below cmdlet for just this purpose. It will create a proxy on the fly which lasts only for the duration of the current pipeline.

A full writeup is on my blog [here](http://www.latkin.org/blog/2012/04/25/how-to-capture-or-redirect-write-host-output-in-powershell/), but I've included the code below. Use the `-Quiet` switch to suppress the console write.

Usage:

```
PS> .\SomeScriptWithWriteHost.ps1 | Select-WriteHost | out-file .\data.log  # Pipeline usage
PS> Select-WriteHost { .\SomeScriptWithWriteHost.ps1 } | out-file .\data.log  # Scriptblock usage (safer)

function Select-WriteHost
{
   [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'FromPipeline')]
   param(
     [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ParameterSetName = 'FromPipeline')]
     [object] $InputObject,

     [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'FromScriptblock', Position = 0)]
     [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock,

     [switch] $Quiet
   )

   begin
   {
     function Cleanup
     {
       # Clear out our proxy version of write-host
       remove-item function:\write-host -ea 0
     }

     function ReplaceWriteHost([switch] $Quiet, [string] $Scope)
     {
         # Create a proxy for write-host
         $metaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host')
         $proxy = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::create($metaData)

         # Change its behavior
         $content = if($quiet)
                    {
                       # In quiet mode, whack the entire function body,
                       # simply pass input directly to the pipeline
                       $proxy -replace '(?s)\bbegin\b.+', '$Object'
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       # In noisy mode, pass input to the pipeline, but allow
                       # real Write-Host to process as well
                       $proxy -replace '(\$steppablePipeline\.Process)', '$Object; $1'
                    }

         # Load our version into the specified scope
         Invoke-Expression "function ${scope}:Write-Host { $content }"
     }

     Cleanup

     # If we are running at the end of a pipeline, we need
     #    to immediately inject our version into global
     #    scope, so that everybody else in the pipeline
     #    uses it. This works great, but it is dangerous
     #    if we don't clean up properly.
     if($pscmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'FromPipeline')
     {
        ReplaceWriteHost -Quiet:$quiet -Scope 'global'
     }
   }

   process
   {
      # If a scriptblock was passed to us, then we can declare
      #   our version as local scope and let the runtime take
      #   it out of scope for us. It is much safer, but it
      #   won't work in the pipeline scenario.
      #
      #   The scriptblock will inherit our version automatically
      #   as it's in a child scope.
      if($pscmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'FromScriptBlock')
      {
        . ReplaceWriteHost -Quiet:$quiet -Scope 'local'
        & $scriptblock
      }
      else
      {
         # In a pipeline scenario, just pass input along
         $InputObject
      }
   }

   end
   {
      Cleanup
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can run your script in a secondary PowerShell shell and capture the output like this:

```
powershell -File 'Your-Script.ps1' > output.log
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Works great! Best solution I've found that doesn't require any changes to code or proxy functions. KISS

Comment: This worked for `Write-Output` but did not work for `Write-Host`.  [Emiliano Poggi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5752877/)'s answer seems more complete.

Answer (score 9):

Using redirection will cause [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) to hang. This is because Write-Host deals with various formatting issues that are specific to the current terminal being used. If you just want your script to have flexibility to output as normal (default to shell, with capability for `>`, `2>`, etc.), use [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output?view=powershell-5.1).

Otherwise, if you really want to capture the peculiarities of the current terminal, [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript) is a good place to start. Otherwise you'll have to hand-test or write some complicated test suites.

Comment: I would nominate this answer as the correct answer since it basically states you cannot redirect write-host and instead suggests what to use in its place

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. I'm not sure why it isn't?? ;)

Answer (score 7):

Try adding a asterisk `*` before the angle bracket `>` to redirect all streams:

> powershell -File Your-Script.ps1 `*`> output.log

When stream redirection is requested, if no specific stream is indicated then by default only the `Success Stream`(`1>`) is redirected. `Write-Host` is an alias for `Write-Information` which writes to the `Information Stream` (`6>`). To redirect all streams use `*>`.

[Powershell-7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1) supports redirection of multiple output streams:

- Success Stream (#1): PowerShell 2.0   `Write-Output`
- Error Stream (#2): PowerShell 2.0 `Write-Error`
- Warning Stream (#3): PowerShell 3.0   `Write-Warning`
- Verbose Stream (#4): PowerShell 3.0   `Write-Verbose`
- Debug Stream (#5): PowerShell 3.0 `Write-Debug`
- Information Stream (#6): PowerShell 5.0   `Write-Information`
- All Streams (*): PowerShell 3.0

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in my first PowerShell script that I wrote few days back:

```
function logMsg($msg)
{
    Write-Output $msg
    Write-Host   $msg
}
```

Usage in a script:

```
logMsg("My error message")
logMsg("My info message")
```

PowerShell script execution call:

```
ps> .\myFirstScript.ps1 >> testOutputFile.txt
```

It's not exactly answer to this question, but it might help someone trying to achieve both logging to the console and output to some log file, doing what I reached here :)

Comment: Be careful with this approach. Anything you write with write-output becomes part of the return value of the function, which can be surprising, especially if there is an explicit return statement later in the function.

Answer (score 3):

If you have just a few Write-Host statements, you can use the `"6>>"` redirector operator to a file:

`Write-Host "Your message." 6>> file_path_or_file_name`

This is the ["Example 5: Suppress output from Write-Host"](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host?view=powershell-6#examples) provided by Microsoft, modified accordingly to [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6).

Comment: "6" means: *"Information Stream. Introduced in PowerShell 5.0."*

Answer (score 2):

Define a function called Write-Host. Have it write to a file. You may have some trouble if some invocations use a weird set of arguments. Also, this will only work for invocations that are not Snapin qualified.

Answer (score 1):

I just added [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript) at the top of the script and [Stop-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript) at the bottom.

The output file was intended to be named `<folder where script resides>-<datestamp>.rtf`, but for some reason the trace file was being put where I did not expect it — the desktop!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Write-Host if you wish to have the messages in a file.  It is for writing to the host only.

Instead you should use a logging module, or Set/Add-Content.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best way to handle this is to have a logging function that will detect if there is a host UI and act accordingly. When the script is executed in interactive mode it will show the details in the host UI, but when it is run via WinRM or in a non-interactive mode it will fall back on the [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output?view=powershell-5.1)  so that you can capture it using the `>` or `*>` [redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347588.aspx)

```
function Log-Info ($msg, $color = "Blue") {
    if($host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "`n[$([datetime]::Now.ToLongTimeString())] $msg" -ForegroundColor $color -BackgroundColor "Gray"
    } else {
        Write-Output "`r`n[$([datetime]::Now.ToLongTimeString())] $msg"
    }
}
```

In cases where you want to capture the full output with the [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) coloring, you can use the [Get-ConsoleAsHtml.ps1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/11/colorized-capture-of-console-screen-in-html-and-rtf.aspx) script to export the host's scrolling buffer to an HTML or [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) file.

Comment: Write-Output can be dangerous if someone uses the function Log-Info inside a pipeline or a function. You'll have then suddenly the console output in the pipeline or as function return value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output?view=powershell-5.1) instead of [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host), and redirect it to a file like this:

```
Deploy.ps1 > mylog.log or Write-Output "Hello World!" > mylog.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output) instead of [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host).

The output goes down the pipeline, but if this is the end of the pipe, it goes to the console.

```
> Write-Output "test"
test
> Write-Output "test" > foo.txt
> Get-Content foo.txt
test
```