# Restore Powershell functions

Tags: powershell

This may seem like a total newb question, because it is...

I was testing some customised functions, specifically a function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952811/hide-write-host-outputs) to suppress Write-Host.
This deleted the original Powershell Write-Host function.

I have googled for a while but I can't find a way to restore the Powershell functions to "factory settings".

Does anyone know how to get the standard Write-Host back?

Comment: are u on v5 or v7?

Comment: v5. Maybe I should update, too?

Comment: Just remove it and start a new instance of powershell.exe - the script in the second answer to the post you linked only removes it from the current session

Comment: Doh! Thanks! I feel a bit stupid now. I had already tried to close and reopen the Powershell window, but I had others open. When I closed all, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Answered by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322127/restore-powershell-functions/62323183#comment110223783_62322127):

> Just remove it and start a new instance of powershell.exe - the script in the second answer to the post you linked only removes it from the current session