# PowerShell Redirection Does Not Always Work

Tags: powershell

Redirecting the **Warning Stream** for `New-PSSession` does not work as I believe it should. I am always getting the following (**yellow**) warning message to console regardless of what I do to try suppress / redirect it:

```bsh
WARNING: Using New-PSSession with Basic Authentication is going to be deprecated soon, checkout https://aka.ms/exops-docs for using Exchange Online V2 Module which uses Modern Authentication.
```

What am I missing about PowerShell redirection / streams that's allowing that message to permeate through to the console / std_out?

## What doesn't work

I have tried the following, as per *the wisdom of the internet*:

```bsh
New-PSSession *>$null ...
```

```bsh
New-PSSession ... | Out-Null
```

```bsh
New-PSSession *>$null ... -OutVariable x -ErrorVariable y -WarningVariable z
```

```bsh
New-PSSession *>$null ... -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

```bsh
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
New-PSSession ...
```

I've even tried taking temporary control of `std_out`:

```bsh
$std_out = [System.Console]::Out
$out_writer = New-Object IO.StringWriter
[System.Console]::SetOut($out_writer)

$std_err = [System.Console]::Error
$err_writer = New-Object IO.StringWriter
[System.Console]::SetOut($err_writer)

$sess = New-PSSession ...

[System.Console]::SetOut($std_out)
[System.Console]::SetError($std_err)
```

Along with every combination of above that I can think of, plus several more methods that I'm forgetting.

## What *should* work

Testing each of those techniques using `Invoke-Command` works for other warnings, as expected:

```bsh
$std_out = [System.Console]::Out
$out_writer = New-Object IO.StringWriter
[System.Console]::SetOut($out_writer)

$std_err = [System.Console]::Error
$err_writer = New-Object IO.StringWriter
[System.Console]::SetOut($err_writer)

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {

    Write-Error "My Error"
    Write-Warning "My Warning"
    [console]::WriteLine('Directly to std_out!')

} *>$null -OutVariable x -ErrorVariable y -WarningVariable z

[System.Console]::SetOut($std_out)
[System.Console]::SetError($std_err)
```

But nothing I have tried will suppress or redirect that message from `New-PSSession`.

## To reproduce

```bsh
param (
    $username,
    $password
)

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpasswd)
$URL = "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell"
New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $URL -Credential $creds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

## Environments Tested

Windows 10:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.0-preview.2
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.0-preview.2
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Windows 10:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Server 2019:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.1007
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.1007
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

WinRM (Identical for all systems):

```
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = false
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

Comment: `3>$null` or `*>$null` should work, but I cannot duplicate that particular warning here to verify.

Comment: Works for me.  `$('hi'; write-warning warning) 3>$null`

Comment: i cannot duplicate as basic authentication is not recommanded, but what about adding " -WarningAction SilentlyContinue" ?

Comment: @Brice Thanks for the suggestion, but that is one of the "several more methods" I mention. I'll update the answer to include it.

Comment: I don't get that error when I try it, `.\test joe here`.  I can hide other warnings in the usual way.

Comment: @js2010 It is related to the `New-PSSession` cmdlet when used to connect to an exchange server. Not a general problem with warnings.

Comment: @js2010 Have you tried logging in with a real user/pass? Errors / Warnings about bad user pass will get suppressed, as per the question's details. The warning I'm referring to will only occur if you successfully login.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, redirecting the output works like you already tried. To be more specific:

```
New-PSSession -... 3> $null
```

would redirect your unwanted warning, as `3` describes the Warning Stream since PowerShell 3.0 ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)).

The fact that it does not work in this particular case seems to be a bug and there has already been opened an issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/5454) a few days ago.

---

There might be a possible explanation in [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/):

> This happens because **Write-Host is not written to any stream**. It's
>   sent to the host program, and the host program decides what to do with
>   it. The Windows PowerShell console and Windows PowerShell ISE display
>   host messages on the console.

Well, it is not correct anymore (since PowerShell 5.0), as `Write-Host` is now a wrapper for `Write-Information` and thus writes to the Information Stream (6). But what is interesting, is the fact that there are host messages that are not written to any stream. This might be the case here, where you are not able to suppress a console output by redirecting all streams. So the "warning" is probably forwarded by a host message instead of using any stream.

I saw several attempts to suppress those host messages ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14470953/11942268) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5588689/11942268)), but as far as I can tell, nothing would help in your case.

The cited article further states:

> [...] messages to the host program (which can't be suppressed or
>   redirected).

Comment: Thanks for linking the GitHub issue, I did not see it on my travels. I have linked this question and my own [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12563) on the PowerShell repo.

Comment: FYI, there is a workaround mentioned in the bug report:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/5454#issuecomment-624162375

basically add HideBannermessage=true to the request.

Comment: @user2199860 I have a few workarounds, but my issue boils down to two things: 1. I want a general solution to handle all warnings from any command / script. 2. I don't want to suppress warnings - they're there for a reason.

Comment: For a slightly more in-depth discussion about the issue, albeit a sadly apathetic response, see: [this thread](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12563)

Comment: @RichardDunn Sad. But I like [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12563#issuecomment-624643630) code to reproduce the problem, because everyone can run it in an offline environment (after `Enable-PSRemoting; Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`). You should probably add these repro steps for future readers. In my edit I point out that it might be worth looking into "host messages" to proceed in your case.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, but `Write-Host` is already captured by my `Invoke-Command` wrapper.

Comment: @RichardDunn I mean less the cmdlet `Write-Host` as the fact that there are "host messages". I'd try looking into how to access/influence them. Might be a setting or behaviour of the console. Maybe the [answer of Tuckbros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61740151/11942268) is exactly doing that.

Comment: In my question you'll see a section regarding this: "I've even tried taking temporary control of std_out". @Tuckbros pertains to this, but I'm not sure if there's some subtle differences, I have yet to check. However, if you read this (authoritative) comment on the [PowerShell GitHub page](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12563#issuecomment-624772456), you find that there's apparently no solution. Reading between the lines, there's an internal mechanism to access the standard out writer regardless of how the programmer tries to override it. Redirection is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an answer but too long for a comment. Don't ask me to explain what it does nor how it works. 
It was found somewhere here or somewhere else. I put it here because it seems to be related to powershell and some kind of thread interactions... I let you take what you need out of it.

Here was our context : We had to run a powershell script from a bat script. The powershell script was launching some system command (zip and so on). We had hard time to collect runtime informations the right way. As a solution we had to pass the ps1 script as a parameter of another ps1 script which we called `bug.ps1`. Its content is shown below.

Here is the command in the .bat file :

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "C:\path\to\bug.ps1" "my_script.ps1" %arg%
```

and here is the content of the bug.ps1 file

```
# <fix>
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
$objectRef = $host.GetType().GetField( "externalHostRef", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $host )
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetProperty"
$consoleHost = $objectRef.GetType().GetProperty( "Value", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $objectRef, @() )
[void] $consoleHost.GetType().GetProperty( "IsStandardOutputRedirected", $bindingFlags ).GetValue( $consoleHost, @() )
$bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance,NonPublic,GetField"
$field = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField( "standardOutputWriter", $bindingFlags )
$field.SetValue( $consoleHost, [Console]::Out )
$field2 = $consoleHost.GetType().GetField( "standardErrorWriter", $bindingFlags )
$field2.SetValue( $consoleHost, [Console]::Out )
# </fix>
invoke-expression "$args"
exit $lastexitcode
```

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting snippet of code. I'll take a better look at it later today. Could prove useful.

Comment: I guess you can just 'prepend'  the `fix` somewhere prior to the command you want to properly redirect