# PowerShell Implicit remoting warning redirection

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm using [Microsoft ExchangePowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps) on an on-premise Exchange (2016 CU19) and I try to catch warning outputs for logging purpose:

1. get the warning (usually with -WarningVariable)
2. hide the warning (usually with -WarningAction or redirection 3>$null)

I don't figure out how to do this 2 things at the same time, any clue or explanation would be appreciated.

I use Windows PowerShell 5.1, ExchangePowerShell is installed on an admin server without the full install of Exchange

## What I've tried

### Using `-WarningAction` and `-WarningVariable`

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity $identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $address -WarningVariable +warnings -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

The warning is hidden but $warnings is empty

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity $identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $address -WarningVariable +Global:warnings
```

The warning is displayed and $warnings is set

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity $identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $address -WarningVariable +warnings
```

The warning is displayed and $warnings is empty

### Wrapping CmdLet with `Invoke-Command`

```
Invoke-Command { Set-Mailbox -Identity $identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $address } -WarningVariable +warnings -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

The warning is displayed and $warnings is set

```
Invoke-Command { Set-Mailbox -Identity $identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $address -WarningVariable +warnings -WarningAction SilentlyContinue }
Invoke-Command { Set-Mailbox -Identity $identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $address -WarningAction SilentlyContinue } -WarningVariable +warnings
Invoke-Command { Set-Mailbox -Identity $identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $address -WarningAction SilentlyContinue } -WarningVariable +Global:warnings
```

The warning is hidden but $warnings is empty

```
Invoke-Command { Set-Mailbox -Identity $identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $address -WarningVariable +warnings } -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

The warning is displayed and $warnings is empty

### Using redirection

Adding `*>$null`, to all previous examples, has no effect, the warning is displayed

This is the main incomprehensible point to me. Why, `-WarningAction` can have an effect on the user interface and the redirection doesn't?

### Using preference variables

No effect

### Directly using session to push variable preference or override `Write-Warning`

This is not possible as the remote session is in [NoLanguage Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes?view=powershell-5.1#no-language-nolanguage) and only Exchange CmdLet are available.

### Using reflection to redirect consolehost output

I don't figure how to do that. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61740151/6014016) doesn't help as signatures and type definitions don't match mine.

Comment: What's with the `+` sign in front of the warningvariable? `-WarningVariable +warnings`

Comment: @Theo To append warning to the variable $warnings. See [-WarningVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1#-warningvariable)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I have never seen that before. Good to know.