# Why Write-Host results are sent to file?

Tags: powershell

I read everywhere (i.e. [Redirect Write-Host statements to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588689)) that `Write-Host` cannot be redirected to file. But

Given `t.ps1` file:

```
function Log(){
    Write-Host "host msg"
}

Log
```

I see "host msg" in file:

```
PS D:\> & ./t.ps1 *>> .\out.log

PS D:\> gc .\out.log
host msg
```

Comment: In PSv5+, `Write-Host` uses the `Information` pipeline (`5`)

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use redirect-all (`*>`) or should use a targeted redirect (`2>&1 3>&1 > file.txt` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can Write-output instead of write-host, to redirect output to a file or use pipe and out-file cmdlet.