# Redirect/Capture Write-Host output even with -NoNewLine

Tags: powershell

The function ***Select-WriteHost*** from an answer to another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588689/redirect-write-host-statements-to-a-file/5590764) *(see code below)* will redirect/capture ***Write-Host*** output:

Example:

```
PS> $test = 'a','b','c' |%{ Write-Host $_ } | Select-WriteHost
a
b
c

PS> $test
a
b
c
```

However, if I add ***-NoNewLine*** to **Write-Host**, **Select-WriteHost** will ignore it:

```
PS> $test = 'a','b','c' |%{ Write-Host -NoNewLine $_ } | Select-WriteHost
abc

PS> $test
a
b
c
```

Can anyone figure out how to modify ***Select-WriteHost*** (code below) to also support ***-NoNewLine***?

```PoSH
function Select-WriteHost
{
   [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'FromPipeline')]
   param(
     [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ParameterSetName = 'FromPipeline')]
     [object] $InputObject,

     [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'FromScriptblock', Position = 0)]
     [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock,

     [switch] $Quiet
   )

   begin
   {
     function Cleanup
     {
       # Clear out our proxy version of write-host
       remove-item function:\write-host -ea 0
     }

     function ReplaceWriteHost([switch] $Quiet, [string] $Scope)
     {
         # Create a proxy for write-host
         $metaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host')
         $proxy = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::create($metaData)

         # Change its behavior
         $content = if($quiet)
                    {
                       # In quiet mode, whack the entire function body,
                       # simply pass input directly to the pipeline
                       $proxy -replace '(?s)\bbegin\b.+', '$Object'
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       # In noisy mode, pass input to the pipeline, but allow
                       # real Write-Host to process as well
                       $proxy -replace '(\$steppablePipeline\.Process)', '$Object; $1'
                    }

         # Load our version into the specified scope
         Invoke-Expression "function ${scope}:Write-Host { $content }"
     }

     Cleanup

     # If we are running at the end of a pipeline, we need
     #    to immediately inject our version into global
     #    scope, so that everybody else in the pipeline
     #    uses it. This works great, but it is dangerous
     #    if we don't clean up properly.
     if($pscmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'FromPipeline')
     {
        ReplaceWriteHost -Quiet:$quiet -Scope 'global'
     }
   }

   process
   {
      # If a scriptblock was passed to us, then we can declare
      #   our version as local scope and let the runtime take
      #   it out of scope for us. It is much safer, but it
      #   won't work in the pipeline scenario.
      #
      #   The scriptblock will inherit our version automatically
      #   as it's in a child scope.
      if($pscmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'FromScriptBlock')
      {
        . ReplaceWriteHost -Quiet:$quiet -Scope 'local'
        & $scriptblock
      }
      else
      {
         # In a pipeline scenario, just pass input along
         $InputObject
      }
   }

   end
   {
      Cleanup
   }
}
```

PS:  I tried inserting ***-NoNewLine*** to the line below (just to see how it would react) however, its producing the exception, *"Missing function body in function declaration"*

```
Invoke-Expression "function ${scope}:Write-Host { $content }"
```

to:

```
Invoke-Expression "function ${scope}:Write-Host -NoNewLine { $content }"
```

Comment: Thanks.. I don't need to use PowerShell <5.  However I am looking for solution  via Select-WriteHost....since that's the function I need to use for redirecting all other write-host cases.

Comment: No it doesn't.  `$test = 'a','b','c' |%{ Write-Host $_ -NoNewline} 6>&1`  will not make $test = "abc".  The whole point is I was looking for a way to capture the text correctly when NoNewLine is used.

Answer (score 1):

- (Just to recap) `Write-Host` is meant for *host*, i.e. *display* / *console* output only, and originally couldn't be captured (in-session) at all. In PowerShell 5, the ability to capture `Write-Host` output was introduced via the *information stream*, whose number is `6`, enabling techniques such as redirection `6>&1` in order to merge `Write-Host` output into the *success (output) stream* (whose number is `1`), where it can be captured as usual.
- However, due to your desire to use the `-NoNewLine` switch *across several calls*, `6>&1` by itself is *not* enough, because the concept of not emitting a newline only applies to *display* output, not to distinct objects in the pipeline.

  - E.g., in the following call `-NoNewLine` is effectively *ignored*, because there are *multiple* `Write-Host` calls producing *multiple* output objects (strings) that are captured separately:

    - `'a','b','c' |  % { Write-Host $_ -NoNewline } 6>&1`
  - Your `Select-WriteHost` function - necessary in PowerShell 4 and below only - would have the same problem if you adapted it to support the `-NoNewLine` switch.
- An aside re `6>&1`: The *strings* that `Write-Host` invariably outputs are wrapped in [`[System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord) instances, due to being re-routed via the information stream. In *display* output you will not notice the difference, but to get the actual string you need to access the `.MessageData.Message` property or simply call `.ToString()`.

---

There is no *general* solution I am aware of, but situationally the following may work:

- If you know that the code of interest uses *only* `Write-Host -NoNewLine` calls:

Simply join the resulting strings *after the fact* without a separator to emulate `-NoNewLine` behavior:

```
# -> 'abc'
# Note: Whether or not you use -NoNewLine here makes no difference.
-join ('a','b','c' | % { Write-Host -NoNewLine $_ })
```

- If you know that all instances of `Write-Host -NoNewLine` calls apply only to *their respective pipeline input*, you can write a simplified proxy function that *collects all input up front* and performs separator-less concatenation of the stringified objects:

```
# -> 'abc'
$test = & {

  # Simplified proxy function
  function Write-Host {
    param([switch] $NoNewLine)
    if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { $allInput = $Input } 
    else                              { $allInput = $args }
    if ($NoNewLine) { -join $allInput.ForEach({ "$_" }) }
    else            { $allInput.ForEach({ "$_" })  }
  }

  # Important: pipe all input directly.
  'a','b','c' | Write-Host -NoNewLine

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am just looking for a replacement for `Select-WriteHost`; except with the ability to also handle `-nonewline`.  When I tried to use your Write-Host (renamed to Select-WriteHost2), $test doesn't have a value.  `$test = 'a','b','c' |%{ Write-Host -NoNewLine $_ } | Select-WriteHost2`

Comment: PS:  I tried to integrate your proxy code into the original Select-WriteHost code I posted.. however, can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @MKANET, my solution is designed to _override_ `Write-Host`, so renaming it won't work. As stated, I don't think there's a solution for _multiple_ `Write-Host -NoNewLine` calls - only for a _single_ one to which all inputs are piped _directly_. If you can ensure that,  you can rewrite `Select-WriteHost` to do what the `Write-Host` function in this answer does, i.e. you need to _collect all input objects first_ and act on the resulting collection.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to provide an answer.  It really isn't a solution to my question. However, at least you confirmed that it's not possible to do what I want.